# How to format string in JS?

Tags: javascript, string, replace, format

I would like to have the result :

`28,12,2016`
From this string `"28/12/2016"`

I tried :

```
("28/12/2016").replace('/',',');

 ==>"28,12/2016"
```

I don't know how to delete the second `/`and the `" "`

Answer (score 1):

use split and join method

```js
var a="28/12/2016";
var ans=a.split("/").join(",");
console.log(ans);
```